# writerow only write one row

Tags: python, csv, pycharm

how come my writerow code in a for loop only write 1 row into the csv file. My codes are:

```
for row in announcements_df:

    row['Date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'] + row['Time'], '%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S')
    data_writer = csv.DictWriter(open('announcements_date_formated.csv', 'wb'), fieldnames=['asxCode', 'CompanyName', 'Date', 'Time', 'Header', 'page', 'MarketSensitive', 'hour', 'minutes', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'Date2'])
    data_writer.writeheader()
    data_writer.writerow(row)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Please indent your code. It matters in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for each row you reopen the file for writing, so you overwrite the previous content. Move the line with `open()` outside of the loop. And the header part as well.

Answer (score 1):

You code should look like this, instead:

```
with open('announcements_date_formated.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    data_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['asxCode', 'CompanyName', 'Date', 'Time', 'Header', 'page', 'MarketSensitive', 'hour', 'minutes', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'Date2'])
    data_writer.writeheader()

    for row in announcements_df:
        row['Date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'] + row['Time'], '%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S')
        data_writer.writerow(row)
```

As [JulienD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293440/3125566) already mentioned, you're opening the file all over again, every time you loop